# Return filename of specific pattern which was last modified from s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I am writing a python script where I have to fetch just the filename (Eg. 'abc.csv') from a directory in a S3 Bucket which was last modified. I have managed to fetch the filename from the bucket but not according to last modified timestamp.

```
def filename_retrieve():

    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3',
                    aws_access_key_id=optsconfig.aws_access_key_id,
                    aws_secret_access_key=optsconfig.aws_secret_access_key,
                    )

    bucket = optsconfig.SOURCE_CONTACT_BKT
    folder = optsconfig.s3_SC_OPTS_archive
    s3_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket)

    files_in_s3 = [f.key.split(folder + "/")[0] for f in s3_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=optsconfig.s3_SC_OPTS_archive).all()]

    for files in files_in_s3:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(files, '*_LEAD_*.csv'):
            print(max(files, key=lambda x: x.stat().st_ctime))
            #print(os.path.basename(files))



filename_retrieve()
```